# Constructing Tauc Plots

Tags: semiconductor-physics

How can we construct a [tauc plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauc_plot) using data from the transmission spectra? How does one calculate the absorption coefficient for plotting tauc plots?

Answer (score 2):

The absorption coefficient, $\alpha$, is defined by:

$$ \frac{I}{I_0} = e^{-\alpha z} $$

where $I$ is the intensity of the transmitted light and $I_0$ is the intensity of the incident light and $z$ is the optical path length (typically the film thickness). In a transmission spectrum you measure $T$ where $T = I/I_0$, so:

$$ \alpha = - \frac{\ln T}{z} $$

Answer (score 0):

we know from Beer Lambert law  I=I0 exp(-Alpha *t)

thus, In (I0/I) = alpha*t

```
      Alpha = (2.303*A)/ t
```

where I0=  incident intensity
I= transmitted intensity
alpha = absorption co efficient 
t = Thickness of the material 
A= absorbence